# CLion. Как изменить шаблонный файл GoogleTests?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, clion, google-test

При подключении google tests через CMake создается шаблонный файл hello_test.cc. Его нельзя переименовать и изменить его расширение на .cpp. В этот каталог так-же нельзя класть другие google-test файлы, потому что #include <gtest.h> не обнаруживается.

Делал все те-же самые действия в Visual Studio 19, там все корректно работает, изменяется, добавляется. 
Вопрос как решить данную проблему?

[image: CLion CMake]

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(google)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        googletest
        URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

add_executable(google src/main.cpp)

file(GLOB tests
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/google_tests/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/google_tests/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/google_tests/*.cc"
        )

add_executable(
        google_test
        ${tests}
)

target_link_libraries(
        google_test
        gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(google_test)
```

Comment: Ничего там не создается.

Comment: Каждый раз, когда пишите слово "нельзя", нужно уточнять, как это происходит. Например, не компилируется, тогда какая ошибка. Крепится, тогда стектрейс. И так далее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При каждой правке надо было каждый раз CMakeLists.txt перезагружать и тогда все работает хорошо. Вообщем я криворукий рукожоп.
Действительно, там никакого файла не создаётся.